# Data not being sent to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata

Hi I am pretty new to Android development and I'm having some issues introducing CRUD via Firbase RTDB My code is not sending the data to Firebase RTDB, I thought at first the button wasn't registering any clicks or it wasn't reading the input but I added a new button to clear entered text from the view and some printlns to print out the entered text to the console which all works as expected

```
class CreatePlayerFragment: Fragment(), AnkoLogger {

    private lateinit var viewModel: CharacterViewModel


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CharacterViewModel::class.java)
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_player, container, false)

    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //        display message on succesful character creation, display dynamic error message on failure
        viewModel.result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val message = if (it == null) {
                getString(R.string.character_added)
            } else {0
                getString(R.string.character_failure, it.message)
            }
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })

        //listener for submission button
        submit.setOnClickListener {
            val name: String = editTextPlayerName.text.toString().trim()
            val race: String = editTextRace.text.toString().trim()
            val classType: String = editTextClass.text.toString().trim()
            info("button clicked")
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

                input_layout_name.error = getString(R.string.field_required_error)
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            val character = CharacterModel()
            character.name = name
            character.race = race
            character.classType = classType
            viewModel.addCharacter(character)
            println(name)
            println(race)
            println(classType)

        }

        clear.setOnClickListener {
            editTextPlayerName.getText().clear()
            editTextRace.getText().clear()
            editTextClass.getText().clear()
        }

    }

}
```

this is the code for my CharacterViewModel

```
class CharacterViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val dbCharacterModels = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(NODE_CHARACTERS)

    private val _result = MutableLiveData<Exception?>()
    val result: LiveData<Exception?>
        get() = _result

    /*
        Add character to DB, save a character under the characters node in the DB with a
        unique key id.

     */
    fun addCharacter(character: CharacterModel) {

        character.id = dbCharacterModels.push().key
        dbCharacterModels.child(character.id!!).setValue(character).addOnCompleteListener {
            if(it.isSuccessful){
                _result.value = null
            } else {
                _result.value = it.exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT
Added some logs for when I submit

```
2020-12-27 15:56:11.824 2956-2956/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
2020-12-27 15:56:11.843 2123-3463/? I/system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
2020-12-27 15:56:11.857 2956-2956/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.BIND_SHARED_PREFS pkg=com.google.android.gms }
2020-12-27 15:56:11.857 2956-2956/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.BIND_SHARED_PREFS pkg=com.google.android.gms }
2020-12-27 15:56:11.862 2956-2956/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.BIND_SHARED_PREFS pkg=com.google.android.gms }
2020-12-27 15:56:11.870 2956-2956/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.BIND_SHARED_PREFS pkg=com.google.android.gms }
2020-12-27 15:56:11.870 2956-2956/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.BIND_SHARED_PREFS pkg=com.google.android.gms }
2020-12-27 15:56:11.875 2956-2956/? D/BoundBrokerSvc: onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.BIND_SHARED_PREFS pkg=com.google.android.gms }
2020-12-27 15:56:12.686 31048-31048/org.wit.guildmanagerapp I/CreatePlayerFragment: button clicked
2020-12-27 15:56:12.687 31048-31048/org.wit.guildmanagerapp I/System.out: bob
2020-12-27 15:56:12.687 31048-31048/org.wit.guildmanagerapp I/System.out: Human
2020-12-27 15:56:12.687 31048-31048/org.wit.guildmanagerapp I/System.out: Mage
2020-12-27 15:56:12.694 2123-3463/? I/system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
2020-12-27 15:56:12.794 173-173/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=4064 uid=2000 name=car_service scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
2020-12-27 15:56:12.794 4064-4064/? W/cmd: Can't find service car_service
```

also this error I read could be fixed by adding allow clear text into the androidManifest but it still appears anyway

```
2020-12-27 15:56:23.831 489-489/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-12-27 15:56:23.831 489-489/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
```

Comment: please capture error logs and update in your question

Comment: @Amod Gokhale there are no error logs, its compiling and not giving any errors when I hit the button

Comment: can you add `addOnFailureListener` and log the error and update the question with it

Comment: where exactly do I add the addOnFailureListener?

Comment: cascaded to `.addOnCompleteListener` .. please use @Zain if you post messages directed to me to receive a notification of that